# What is the correct datatype to use in the SSIS data flow when moving a JSONB[] datatype to and from Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, ssis, metadata

I have a column in Postgres that is declared as a JSONB datatype and I am attempting to move data from one PostgreSQL server to another using SSIS (cannot clone DB in current environment). The data is stored in UNICODE. I am using the `Intellisoft OLE DB Provider for PostreSQL` OLE DB Provider - it can be found here: https://www.pgoledb.com/index.php/purchase. I have a trial version of the Desktop Edition.

What is the correct datatype to use in SSIS when loading a JSONB datatype into a PostgreSQL server? Am I using the correct OLE DB Provider?

Problem:

I can get the JSON data into the data flow and cast the data as either DT_WSTR (Length 4000) or DT_NTEXT without any problems. But, when I try to load it to the destination PostgreSQL server, I get the following error on the destination component.

> [OLE DB Destination [11]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An
>   OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Intellisoft OLE DB Provider for PostgreSQL" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "**ERROR:  column** "ColumnName"
>   **is of type jsonb[] but expression is of type character varying** LINE 1:
>   ...$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30)

I tried performing a data conversion on the both the DT_NTEXT and DT_WSTR to DT_BYTES.

For the DT_NTEXT, that does nothing because when I open the data conversion component back up again, it automatically changes the conversion back to DT_NTEXT.

For the DT_WSTR, I set the DT_BYTES length to 4000, but that results in a truncation error on the conversion component (see error message below).

> [Data Conversion [2]] Error: Data conversion failed while converting
>   column "ColumnName" (143) to column "Copy of ColumnName" (6).  The
>   conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could
>   not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

**Update**

I tried wiring a Source and destination component where the source is set to Table View, meaning there was no SQL command. On the source's Advanced Properties editor, the JSON column is being outputted as DT_NTEXT.

Comment: You mentioned your source column is varchar wit hno length defined. Can you cast your source to stream aka text

Comment: @KeithL Please see the update to my question.

Comment: @KeithL I have completely re-worded my question. Can you please take a look?

Comment: I suggest you try casting to varchar directly in your SQL Select statement before it arrives in SSIS, then cast back. I can't easily work out how to do this from the docs though

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I tried that and it did not work

Comment: "did not work" is meaningless. I haven't used postgres let alone the jsonb data type but the usual solution to working with datatypes that SSIS doesn't like is to cast it to something friendlier. Perhaps you could edit your question and state what you tried and what happened.

Comment: @Nick.Mcerdermaid I do not think the problem is with SSIS, it moves the data from the source to the destination just fine. The error is coming from the 3rd party destination component. I have clarified my question to be more clear on the problem. My apologies for any confusion.

Comment: The error is that you're trying to load a varchar into a jsonb. So I know it sounds complicated but you need to load your varchar into a varchar and then when it's in the database, convert it to jsonb (with an update or insert statement). Then you can ee if it survived the round trip. So try adding an extra varchar column to your target table, load the data into that, then run an update statement when you're done

Comment: I was afraid of that. It seems odd that it reads as VARCHAR even when the meta data viewer shows it is a text stream. Do toy think it could be an issue with three connection manager?

Comment: Rereading your question... did you try just copying it straight through? What error do you get then? (i.e. if you don't "cast the data")

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I tried that, but it did not work. In the advance properties editor on the source, the column is set to DT_NTEXT. This makes sense because SSIS has to cast the data to something because the source and destination are both JSONB[], but SSIS does not support that datatype natively within the data flow.

Comment: Can you use pgdump to transfer the data? Or is that what you mean by clone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the OLE DB driver was the problem. A patch released today adds support for the JSONB[] data type. Upgrade to version 1.4.0.3590.

https://www.pgoledb.com/index.php/products/history

Comment: I never understood what possible use a `jsonb[]` would have. I find it much more sensible to store a json array inside a "plain" `jsonb` column

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name jsonb[] is supposed to be faster. https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-operations-with-the-jsonb-data-type-in-postgresql/  &  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html

Comment: I am talking about `jsonb[]` vs `jsonb` (array of JSON values, vs a "single" JSON value) not about `json` vs. `jsonb`